# How can I add something before a string separated list?

Tags: javascript

Small question: I've this list of file types here:

```
sql,7z,ace,bz2,dmg,gz,rar,tgz,zip,csv,doc,docx,html,key,keynote,odp,ods,odt,pages,pdf,pps,ppt,pptx,rtf,tex,txt,xls,xlsx,xml,bmp,exif,gif,ico,jpeg,jpg,png,psd,tif,tiff,aac,aif,aiff,alac,amr,au,cdda,flac,m3u,m4a,m4p,mid,mp3,mp4,mpa,ogg,pac,ra,wav,wma,3gp,asf,avi,flv,m4v,mkv,mov,mpeg,mpg,rm,swf,vob,wmv,css,img,php
```

The point is that I need to re-format it inside JavaScript so that it looks like this after re-formatting them:

```
.sql, .7z, .ace, .bz2, .dmg, .gz, .rar, .tgz, .zip
```

How can I reach this?

Comment: replace all "," with ", ." and append "." at the beginning

Comment: What’s the stack or at the very least programming language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var fileTypes = 'sql,7z,ace,bz2,dmg,gz,rar,tgz,zip,csv,doc,docx,html,key,keynote,odp,ods,odt,pages,pdf,pps,ppt,pptx,rtf,tex,txt,xls,xlsx,xml,bmp,exif,gif,ico,jpeg,jpg,png,psd,tif,tiff,aac,aif,aiff,alac,amr,au,cdda,flac,m3u,m4a,m4p,mid,mp3,mp4,mpa,ogg,pac,ra,wav,wma,3gp,asf,avi,flv,m4v,mkv,mov,mpeg,mpg,rm,swf,vob,wmv,css,img,php'.split(',').map(function(ft) { return '.' + ft}).join(', ');

console.log(fileTypes);
```

Comment: that last bit is important! `.split(',').map(function(ft) { return '.' + ft}).join(', ');`